# How to open rdl Created with Visual Studio 2005, in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I need to open an SSRS report that was created in Visual Studio 2005. **To include HTML renderining, I need to convert or upgrade the file.**

How to edit SSRS 2005 Reports in Visual Studio 2008 with included data source?

The File is opening in Design mode correctly but code is getting changed. Confuse with **handling data source** as both having different structure.

Please update!!

Answer (score 0):

It automatically convert with all required changes. Data Source remained same.